# Resharper won't run nunit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit, resharper

I am running VS 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4 with Resharper version 8.2.1 and nUnit version 2.6.3.13283.  I wrote this test and completed the code to make it pass and when I ran the test it wouldn't run. Here is the test

[image]

Actually it sort of runs.  When I right-click on the test symbol and choose debug, something runs.  The breakpoint (along with a couple in the code under test) goes white, but it never gets hit and then whatever is happening exits and when I go to the test session window it says it was not run.

[image]

And all of my other tests in the test project are now behaving that way.  The only thing that changed was that I did some refactoring and changes some namespaces in the project.  So there must be a file somewhere that has outdated information.  Where all do I need to delete temporary files that might be harboring outdated names?

Comment: If you look in the VS Test Explorer, does that behave the same way ?  Also, if you look in the Output window for Tests, are there any error messages there ?

Comment: In my experience Resharper does have bugs and sometimes would not run all the tests. I would try to run them with NUnit GUI tool to see if the problem is in Resharper or in the project itself

Comment: Also NUnit GUI sometimes provides better diagnostic on why the test was not run